# Read large file using vertx

Tags: vert.x

I am new to using vertx and I am using vertx filesystem api to read file of large size.

```
vertx.fileSystem().readFile("target/classes/readme.txt", result -> {
    if (result.succeeded()) {
        System.out.println(result.result());
    } else {
        System.err.println("Oh oh ..." + result.cause());
    }
});
```

But the RAM is all consumed while reading and the resource is not even flushed after use. The vertx filesystem api also suggest
**Do not use this method to read very large files or you risk running out of available RAM.**

Is there any alternative to this?

Comment: I think vertx hasn't this kind of api. Why you not reading files with others java solutions?

Answer (score 4):

To read large file you should open an `AsyncFile`:

```
OpenOptions options = new OpenOptions();
fileSystem.open("myfile.txt", options, res -> {
    if (res.succeeded()) {
        AsyncFile file = res.result();
    } else {
        // Something went wrong!
    }
});
```

Then an `AsyncFile` is a `ReadStream` so you can use it together with a Pump to copy the bits to a `WriteStream`:

```
Pump.pump(file, output).start();
file.endHandler((r) -> {
    System.out.println("Copy done");
});
```

There are different kind of `WriteStream`, like `AsyncFile`, net sockets, HTTP server responses, ...etc.

Answer (score 1):

To read/process a large file in chunks you need to use the `open()` method which will return an `AsyncFile` on success. On this `AsyncFile` you `setReadBufferSize()` (or not, the default is 8192), and attach a `handler()` which will be passed a `Buffer` of at most the size of the read buffer you just set.

In the example below I have also attached an `endHandler()` to print a final newline to stay in line with the sample code you provided in the question:

```
vertx.fileSystem().open("target/classes/readme.txt", new OpenOptions().setWrite(false).setCreate(false), result -> {
    if (result.succeeded()) {
        result.result().setReadBufferSize(READ_BUFFER_SIZE).handler(data -> System.out.print(data.toString()))
                                            .endHandler(v -> System.out.println());
    } else {
        System.err.println("Oh oh ..." + result.cause());
    }
});
```

You need to define `READ_BUFFER_SIZE` somewhere of course.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for that is that internally `.readFile` calls to `Files.readAllBytes`.

What you should do instead is create a stream out of your file, and pass it to Vertx handler:

```
    try (InputStream steam = new FileInputStream("target/classes/readme.txt")) {
        // Your handling here
    }
```